# Where does bundle exec rake db:migrate come from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rake-task

I'd to see where this rake task is written and how it finds the db to migrate to.

Comment: [Link](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/2dfe8f1f84b7c4ff6673e7035adbeecaf31734b0/railties/lib/rails/tasks/engine.rake#L31)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This task is part of `ActiveRecord`. You can see where it is defined here : [database_tasks.rb](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/tasks/database_tasks.rb#L164)

Basically the task call `ActiveRecord::Migrator` which is the module in charge of applying migrations to the database.

For example if you create a new migration and you get the following output :

```
Running via Spring preloader in process 4675
      invoke  active_record
      create    db/migrate/20170621091940_create_user.rb
```

When you call the `db:migrate` task it will call `ActiveRecord::Migrator.migrate("db/migrate", 20170621091940)` and apply your migration.

Comment: Thanks @Aschen So rake can be used to do a lot of things, but rails comes with some rake tasks and one of them is db:migrate and it is just a build tool (script) that accesses the `ActiveRecord::Migrator` and then calls its `migrate` method? Is this correct?

Comment: Yes it's correct :-) As @hardik says it also check in the table `schema_migrations` which migrations have already been executed.

Answer (score 2):

The `db:migrate` is a rake task. db:migrate task **(a built-in Rails support program)** will search through your project's db/migrate directory and use the files therein to update the database's schema.

When you run db:migrate, rails will check a special table called schema_migrations which contains the time-stamp of the last migration applied to the database. it will store the times-tamps of the migration files that were already run.

Comment: so this task can be run regardless of have a rails server running?

Comment: Yes, Rake Task don't need server running.